# CSS pseudo before automatic numbering - indentation <p>

Tags: css

```css
p {
  counter-reset: counter;
}
p.counter {
  counter-increment: counter;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
p.counter:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: counter(counter, upper-roman)".";
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #808080;
}
p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #808080;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
hr {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #808080;
}
a:link {
  color: #B2AB19;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: inherent;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B2AB19;
}
a:active {
  color: inherent;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #B2AB19;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
#container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#lcolumn {
  float: left;
  max-width: 250px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#rcolumn {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 250px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body lang="zh-hk">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
      <a href="index.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
      <img src="header.jpg" alt="testing" width=100% height=260>
    </div>
    <div id="lcolumn">
      <p><a href="index.html">Chiayi</a>
      </p>
      <p><a href="index.html">From the Airports</a>
      </p>
      <p><a href="index.html">Places</a>
      </p>
      <p><a href="index.html">Food and Drinks</a>
      </p>
      <p><a href="index.html">Bike Trips</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="rcolumn">
      <h1>Reaching Chiayi City from the Airports by Public Transport</h1>
      <p>Which interational airport will you arrive at?</p>
      <p>&#8226; <a href="#tpe">Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE)</a>
      </p>
      <p>&#8226; <a href="#rmq">Taichung Airport (RMQ)</a>
      </p>
      <p>&#8226; <a href="#khh">Kaohsiung International Airport (KHH)</a>
      </p>
      <hr>
      <h2 id="tpe">Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE)</h2>
      <p class="counter">This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1.
        This is counted 1. This is counted 1.</p>
      <p class="counter">This is counted 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      &#169;2016
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to use pseudo element `:before` for automatic numbering in `p`.

But I have some indentation problem. The numbers are too long. They should be aligned left as of the above lines. The distance between the left of the number and the beginning of the text is `50px`. Please help.

Comment: Please make a **minimal** demo. We don't need your page, just enough to show the issue.

Comment: It's minimal to me because when I have my code not inside the div, I don't have any problems. I had deleted some contents before I posted already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To fix the auto numbering issue, reset the counter on `body` and not `p`.
2. To fix the padding/margin issue, adjust `left: 10px` for `p.counter`

```css
body {
  counter-reset: counter;
}
p.counter {
  counter-increment: counter;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
p.counter:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: counter(counter, upper-roman)".";
  left: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #808080;
}
p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #808080;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
hr {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #808080;
}
a:link {
  color: #B2AB19;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: inherent;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B2AB19;
}
a:active {
  color: inherent;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #B2AB19;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
#container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#lcolumn {
  float: left;
  max-width: 250px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#rcolumn {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 250px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body lang="zh-hk">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
      <a href="index.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
      <img src="header.jpg" alt="testing" width=100% height=260>
    </div>
    <div id="lcolumn">
      <p><a href="index.html">Chiayi</a>
      </p>
      <p><a href="index.html">From the Airports</a>
      </p>
      <p><a href="index.html">Places</a>
      </p>
      <p><a href="index.html">Food and Drinks</a>
      </p>
      <p><a href="index.html">Bike Trips</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="rcolumn">
      <h1>Reaching Chiayi City from the Airports by Public Transport</h1>
      <p>Which interational airport will you arrive at?</p>
      <p>&#8226; <a href="#tpe">Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE)</a>
      </p>
      <p>&#8226; <a href="#rmq">Taichung Airport (RMQ)</a>
      </p>
      <p>&#8226; <a href="#khh">Kaohsiung International Airport (KHH)</a>
      </p>
      <hr>
      <h2 id="tpe">Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE)</h2>
      <p class="counter">This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1. This is counted 1.
        This is counted 1. This is counted 1.</p>
      <p class="counter">This is counted 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      &#169;2016
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. Thank you so much!
2. May I ask a bit more?

p.counter {
  counter-increment: counter;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
p.counter:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: counter(counter, upper-roman)".";
  left: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

How do you come up with the numbers (px)? Sorry that I am too stupid to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: `width` doesn't matter. But `left: 10px` is the one actually needed. `left` needs to be equal to `padding` of `#rcolumn`

Answer (score 1):

Change or remove `width: 50px;` and `padding-left: 50px;`

You have 50px of left padding on the paragraph tags, and the pseudo element is set to 50px in width.

If you don't want that width... adjust it.

Comment: I tried deleting them both and deleting either one and found them no good. Could you advise? Thank you.